# How to handle NSUserNotification closed event

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm showing a notification this way:

```
let notification = NSUserNotification()
notification.title = "Title lorem ipsum"
notification.informativeText = "Lorem ipsum"
notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName
notification.hasActionButton = true
notification.otherButtonTitle = "Other Button"
notification.actionButtonTitle = "Action Button"
NSUserNotificationCenter.default.deliver(notification)
```

Handle notification click events:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: NSUserNotificationCenter, didActivate notification: NSUserNotification) {
        switch (notification.activationType) {
        case .additionalActionClicked:
            print("Action:")
        case .actionButtonClicked:
            print("Action Button clicked")
            takeBreakClicked()
        case .contentsClicked:
            print("Contents clicked") 
        case .none:
            print("none")
        case .replied:
            print("reply clicked")
        }
    }
```

This notification will have 2 buttons. The question is how to get "Other Button" click event?

Comment: What is the question? What did you try? Post your code in the question.

Comment: The question is updated now.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, and the answer isn't particularly satisfying, but maybe it'll save someone some time:

I have arrived at the conclusion that there simply is **no event delivered** when the user clicks the "Close" button in a `NSUserNotification`. (Or whatever you have renamed the "Close" button to using the `otherButtonTitle` property.)